# PHP index.php include file

Tags: php, include

I would like to include external php files into my `index.php` without using:

```
index.php?p=pagetoinclude.php
```

I have it like this now: `index.php?page=home` <- that will include home.php but I have completely forgotten how to do it like this:

`index.php/home/` without "?" but using "/" slash instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

And I should point out that including a page passed in via GET parameter could be extremely insecure unless you're doing the proper checks.

Comment: Im aware, i've allready taken out the $_GET but i used it above as an example. I only use pre-defined variables. but i wanted to use the mod_rewrite to make it just a bit safer. But i remember now.

Thanks for the help mate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use fake clear urls.

On index.php you would get the URL, split it at index.php/ and then parse the rest of the string as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Apache named this kind of feature [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo):

> This directive controls whether requests that contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected. The trailing pathname information can be made available to scripts in the *PATH_INFO* environment variable.
>
> For example, assume the location `/test/` points to a directory that contains only the single file `here.html`. Then requests for `/test/here.html/more` and `/test/nothere.html/more` both collect `/more` as *PATH_INFO*.

You can access that environment variable with [`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server):

> Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual script filename but preceding the query string, if available. For instance, if the current script was accessed via the URL `http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar`, then `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` would contain `/some/stuff`.

If you don’t have an Apache web server or can’t use `AcceptPathInfo`, you probably can use other mechanisms to rewrite such requests to your file and get the path info part from the requested URI somehow.

Comment: I have my own linux server running in rotterdam datacenter, so that aint the problem ahah.

Comment: @Wesley: The note was just for the case that you don’t use Apache but a different web server software (like IIS, lighttpd, nginx, etc.) or that you’re not having your own server or access to its configuration or permission to use it (like on a shared host).